# A doubt about diagonalization of hermitian and not hermitian linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators, hermitian-matrices

In Shankar's *Principle of Quantum Mechanics*, Theorem 10, he says:

> To every **Hermitian** operator $\Omega$, there exists (at least) a basis consisting of its orthonormal eigenvectors. It is diagonal in this eigenbasis and has its eigenvalues as its diagonal entries.

$$
\Omega \leftrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \omega_{2} & 0 & & 0\\
0 & 0 & \omega_{3} & & 0\\
\vdots & & & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & & \omega_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

After that, in the subtopic "**Diagonalization of Hermitian Matrices**" he says:

> If $\Omega$ is a **Hermitian** matrix, there exists a unitary matrix $U$ (built out of the eigenvectors of $\Omega$) such that $U^{\dagger}\Omega U$ is diagonal. Thus the problem of finding a basis that diagonalizes $\Omega$ is equivalent to solving its eigenvalue problem.

---

My doubt appeared when I was working on the exercises. Look at it below:

*Exercise $1.8.5^{*}$* Consider the matrix
$$ \Omega = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
-\sin\theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$$

(1) Show that it is unitary.

(2) Show that its eigenvalues are $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$.

(3) Find the corresponding eigenvectors; show that they are orthogonal.

(4) Verify that $U^{\dagger}\Omega U$ = (diagonal matrix), where U is the matrix of eigenvectors of $\Omega$.

---

On this exercise, we can easily see that $\Omega$ is **not Hermitian** since $\Omega^{\dagger} \neq \Omega$. Nevertheless, when I finished all the tasks of the exercise, it turns out that $U^{\dagger}\Omega U$ = (diagonal matrix) where the diagonal entries were the eigenvalues of $\Omega$, the same results we were learning before that happened when $\Omega$ **was Hermitian**. I want to know whether the following conclusion that I have thought is right:

> If $\Omega$ is a **Hermitian** operator, then **it is undoubtedly possible** to derive a diagonal matrix, by unitary change in basis, whose diagonal entries are the $\Omega$ eigenvalues. **However**, if $\Omega$ **is not Hermitian** it **may or may not** be possible to find a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the $\Omega$ eigenvalues.

I do not want to follow to the other pages before being sure I have understood it right. This final conclusion is correct or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are correct. The first part of your statement is the Spectral Theorem. But it's not hard to come up with examples of the converse.

Comment: Over the real numbers, a matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if it is Hermitian. But over the complex numbers, Hermitian is sufficient but not necessary. The necessary and sufficient condition for orthogonal diagonalizability over $\mathbb{C}$ is *normality*: the matrix must satisfy $\Omega^{\dagger}\Omega = \Omega\Omega^{\dagger}$ (which of course is satisfied by a Hermitian matrix; but not every matrix that satisfies this is Hermitian, as your example shows).

Comment: Thanks a lot to Mr. Adrian and Mr. Arturo. Your explanations are really insightful for me, I won't forget it!